# Could President Obama Legally Serve in President Biden's Cabinet?

Tags: united-states, cabinet

Could President Obama legally serve in President Biden's Cabinet?

I understand that President Obama may not serve as President ever again, but could he serve in another President's Cabinet?

Comment: "I understand that President Obama may not serve as President ever again" Technically, the 22nd Amendment only limits whether one can be "elected President"; it does not explicitly say that a term-limited ex-President are not eligible to be President if they are not elected as such. This is why there is some debate about whether a term-limited ex-President can serve as VP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no restrictions on who can serve in the cabinet based on not being eligible to serve as president due to term limits. If for some reason there was an issue with the line of succession they would be skipped over and the next person in line would step up.

Comment: Exactly. For example Henry Kissinger, born in what is now Germany,  was Secretary of State.

Comment: @Damila Henry Kissinger was born in what was also then Germany.  The fact that it was officially the "Deutsches Reich" rather than the "Bundesrepublik Deutschland" doesn't stop it from being Germany.